# Vectorize two pandas columns at once with CountVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want I want to apply Sklearn's CountVectorizer at two columns at once.
I have tried this:

```
features = df[['col 1', 'col2']]
results = df[['col 3']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False)

features = vectorizer.fit_transform(features)
results = vectorizer.fit_transform(results)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

And then I have tried this:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False)
transformer = make_column_transformer((vectorizer, 'col 1'), (vectorizer, 'col 2'))

features = transformer.fit_transform(features)
results = vectorizer.fit_transform(results)
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

What am I doing wrong, I saw this second solution here:

https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E22AQFC6Uf5_el2nQ/feedshare-shrink_800/0?e=1591228800&v=beta&t=7ZQbbIvgpQKlTfg1Z_IpGT9DB21LUqy_bkKaNE41l0E

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
features = df.iloc[:, [-2,-3]]
results = df.iloc[:, -1]

from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False)
transformer = make_column_transformer((vectorizer, 'col 1'), (vectorizer, 'col 2'))

features = transformer.fit_transform(features)
results = vectorizer.fit_transform(results)
```

Comment: I know it's old but how would that work if I have a list of column names that i don't know in advance ?

Comment: @Chapo you can unpack a list as an argument like this: `make_column_transformer(*[(vectorizer, col) for col in columns])`